# reg unload and new key

Tags: powershell, registry

I can run these commands and everything is as expected

```r
reg load HKU\Kayla C:\Users\Kayla\ntuser.dat
New-Item -Force Registry::HKU\Kayla\Foo
```

However running this after causes an error

```r
PS > reg unload HKU\Kayla
ERROR: Access is denied.
```

If I manually open up the Registry Editor I can unload the hive, but I would
like to unload from a script if possible.

Update: after reading Matt’s answer I found it to work if you run a command
before `collect`ing, example

```r
0
[gc]::collect()
```

It appears the `0` acts as "Recycle Bin" and `collect` is the
“permanent delete”.

Comment: The issue is that loaded key has to be closed first (regardless if modified or not). see also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.close?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit 2015-04-07:** You may need to wait for pending finalizers after forcing garbage collection if you're hosting PowerShell and running in Debug mode. More below.

---

The problem is that `New-Item` creates a handle to the registry key and leaves it open, and you've got to manually close that handle before the GC call can clean it up if it's all running in the same script. (You can see the open handle with Process Explorer's "Find -> Find Handle or DLL..." function; search for your key name in there.)

Fortunately, the result of `New-Item` gives you easy access to that handle:

```r
$result = New-Item # ...
$result.Handle.Close()
```

Now you can `[gc]::Collect()` to clean up the handle and `reg unload`.

In a custom PowerShell host running in Debug mode, because of [differences in GC between Debug and Release modes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165380/1454265), you may have to follow this with a call to `[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`, but please read [the literature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265598/is-correct-to-use-gc-collect-gc-waitforpendingfinalizers), as this can deadlock under certain conditions. In my testing, Release mode works without waiting for pending finalizers.

Full working example for SOME_USER:

```r
$path = "HKLM:\TEMP_hive\newkey" # Key we're going to create.
reg load HKLM\TEMP_hive C:\Users\SOME_USER\NTUSER.DAT
$result = New-Item -Path $path
$result.Handle.Close()
[gc]::Collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() # Optional, and beware of deadlocks! Only seen this needed in Debug mode.
reg unload HKLM\TEMP_hive
```

Note that you do have to be an administrator and running elevated.

**Details:**

In my testing, `[gc]::Collect()` is unable clean up the open handle as long as the same script is running that called `New-Item`. Interestingly, that means in an interactive context like PowerShell ISE, if control returns to the prompt before the `[gc]::Collect()`, it has the same effect and the handle becomes fair game for the collector without even closing it. In PowerShell ISE, run:

```r
$path = "HKLM:\TEMP_hive\differentnewkey" # Key we're going to create.
reg load HKLM\TEMP_hive C:\Users\SOME_USER\NTUSER.DAT
New-Item -Path $path
```

Then run:

```r
[gc]::Collect()
reg unload HKLM\TEMP_hive
```

`reg unload` always succeeds in this context too.

Notice in that last example I no longer assign the return result of New-Item to a variable like $result, because if you do that, you'll still have that handle kicking around as long as $result is in the environment at your prompt, and `reg unload` will fail again. Try it:

```r
$path = "HKLM:\TEMP_hive\thirdnewkey" # Key we're going to create.
reg load HKLM\TEMP_hive C:\Users\SOME_USER\NTUSER.DAT
$result = New-Item -Path $path
```

Then run:

```r
[gc]::Collect()
reg unload HKLM\TEMP_hive
```

Doesn't work until you call `$result.Handle.Close()`.

Also, despite posts around the internet suggesting that there's a timing issue going on, throwing a sleep in there shouldn't change anything (unless you're in the custom host + Debug situation above, in which case I'd recommend waiting on finalizers) — it's all about if that handle is eligible for garbage collection. Would be extremely interested if anyone can explain at a deeper level just what's going on with that handle and the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that there might be a open reference to the hive you have loaded. Running the following command before the unload should clean up the references ( if any )

```
[gc]::collect()
```

More information can be found [here](http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/powershell-loading-and-unloading-registry-hives/)

> This uses the static method Collect from the GC class in .NET which is
>   used for forcing the garbage collector to run and removing those
>   unused references.

**Also**

This might be more of the same thing but just a different approach. Again, with a reference still present `Get-ChildItem variable:` showed a reference to the hive under `$`. Running other command to change the content of that variable seemed to allow the hive unload as well. More on this [here](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/registry-oddity/). For example.

```
Get-ChildItem variable:

Name                           Value                                                     
----                           -----                                                     
$                              HKU\Kayla
```

**In practice**

While this might have not worked for you I tested this myself running with elevated rights.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> reg load HKU\Kayla C:\temp\file.dat
The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\Windows\system32> New-Item -Force Registry::HKU\Kayla\Foo

    Hive: HKU\Kayla

Name                           Property
----                           --------
Foo

PS C:\Windows\system32> reg unload HKU\Kayla
ERROR: Access is denied.
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem variable:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
$                              HKU\Kayla

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem variable:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
$                              variable:

PS C:\Windows\system32> reg unload HKU\Kayla
The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: After testing i could only get consistent results if i ran _anything_ before the collect command. At least it works in a script. I suppose you answered your own question.

Comment: Hey guys, just spent the entire day bashing my head against this - it turns out that the [gc]::Collect() is necessary, but it doesn't clean up the handle to the key in the hive until you've closed the handle manually (or if at a prompt, it goes out of scope). I posted an answer with details.

Answer (score 0):

To completely avoid having to worry about open handles, you can use [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue which will close the handle after setting the value. See Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a5t63w8(v=vs.110).aspx).